# how to save a doc file in PHP?

Tags: php, header, doc

This is my `example.php`, using this i am generating a example.doc file and using header i can save that file in my local computer.

But i want to save one more copy in **report** folder (**report and example.php are in same folder/same domain**)

```
<?php

 $html = preg_replace('%/[^\\s]+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)%i', 'http://www.asd.com\\0', $html);

    print "<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\"";
    print "xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"";
    print "xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\"";
    print "xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">";
    print "<xml>
     <w:WordDocument>
      <w:View>Print</w:View>
      <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
      <w:PunctuationKerning/>
      <w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>
      <w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>
     </w:WordDocument>
    </xml>
    ";
    print '<h1>hello world</h1>';
    header( 'Content-Type: application/msword' );
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=example.doc");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```php
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word');
```

instead of

```php
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
```